# Java Execute Bash Script that runs a daemonized script

Tags: java, linux, bash

I am working on a bash script that is run when My Java server application requests a server reboot. This script does operations that need to be outside of the process tree of the Java application.

I invoke the restart script in Java using ProcessBuilder in the following fashion:

```
// Vars declared at the top of the file
private static final String LOC = "/some/directory/";
private static final String RESTART_SCRIPT = LOC + "restart.sh";
...
// In the function that is invoked to handle reboot behavior
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(RESTART_SCRIPT);
Process p = pb.start();
```

This script does the following to deamonize another script that handles all of the reboot logic. It looks like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
(bash /some/directory/shutdownHandler.sh "true" &)
exit 0
```

When, in the Java Application, I invoke the function containing the ProcessBuilder logic, I do not see the effects of the logic in the shutdownHandler.sh script. Even simple echoes of text into files fails to occur. I already have checked that I have correct permissions.

When I execute restart.sh directly from the command line, it works as expected.

Please advice on why I am seeing this difference in behavior. Is there some way Java is killing the daemonized script?

Comment: Have you tried running bash with the script as an argument?

Comment: Are you referring to the Java ProcessBuilder piece? If so, the restart.sh script does include a shebang line (Which I just edited the question to include). This should mean that the script is invoked using the interpreter in the shebang with the script as the first argument.

Comment: I'm not sure if Java respects the shebang, so explicitly setting the shell may solve the issue

Comment: I'm not sure if Java is able to kill the daemonized process but can you try invoking it with `nohup`? `nohup bash /some/directory/shutdownHandler.sh "true" &`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get the script `shutdownHandler.sh` to trigger correctly in the usage scenario I have described. The issue was in how I was daemonizing `shutdownHandler.sh`. I have changed `restart.sh` to:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOGFILE="/some/log/directory/scriptLog.log"
(setsid /some/directory/shutdownHandler.sh "true" >$LOGFILE 2>&1 < /dev/null &)
exit 0
```

The above does some key things:

- Handle `stdout`, `stderr`, and `stdin` of the script. `stdout` and `stderr` are directed into `LOGFILE` and attaches `dev/null` to `stdin`
- Disconnects from the controlling tty
- Reparents script to init. `shutdownHandler.sh` will not be in the same process tree as the JVM

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the following simplification :

```
final String[] RESTART_COMMAND = { "nohup", "/some/directory/shutdownHandler.sh", "true" };
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(RESTART_COMMAND);
Process p = pb.start();
//DON'T waitFor()
```

Using `nohup` and avoiding to `waitFor` should have the same effect your `RESTART_SCRIPT` implements : both process' lifecycles are independent (the `jvm` doesn't wait for the `shutdownHandler.sh`, termination of the Java process wouldn't lead to an interruption of the `shutdownHandler.sh`).